# A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed .... concurrently using the same instance of DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I got this error when I run unit test.

```
System.InvalidOperationException : A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
```

This is my code. Job2 is similar to Job1. The difference is just the model.

```
public class MyServices : IMyServices
{
    private readonly MyContext _myContext;
    
    public CallQEtlServices(MyContext myContext)
    {
        _myContext = myContext;
    }

public async Task Process(CancellationToken cancellation)
{                              
    await Task.WhenAll(Job1(cancellation),
    Job2(cancellation));
}

public async Task Job1(CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    // code removed for brevity

    _myContext.RemoveRange(myContext.Students);
    await _myContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellation);

    await _myContext.AddRangeAsync(Students, cancellation);
    var result = await _myContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellation);
}
}
```

In program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MyContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(myServicesConnStr),
    ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

and context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(MyContext).Assembly);
    }


    
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task ExecuteSqlRawAsync(string sql)
    {
        await base.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql);
    }        
}
```

Comment: how `myContext` is declared?

Comment: I have just added the context code @viveknuna

Comment: You run Job1 and Job2 in parallel using same DbContext instance and as error tells you - this is not allowed.

Comment: @Evk , any workaround on that?

Comment: Use separate context instances. EF context can't be accessed concurrently by multiple threads by design.